# Codeigniter session xss filtering

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, session, codeigniter-3

does it makes any sense to check if user's session item is xss clean?

Something like this:

```
$item = $this->security->xss_clean($this->session->item);
```

Is there any possibility that session can contain any harmful code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**.

If `$this->session->item` is populated by a malicious user (e.g. some `input textbox` or fake `$_POST`data ) then it is vulnerable to harmful code.

Even if this `session` variable is really stored in your session, it could be inserted in a database, for example.

Comment: Thanks, here is my situation: I am going to store user's language in session `$this->session->lang` is it reasonable here too? If there is any chance that user will manipulate it etc.

Comment: This may sound harsh, but never trust data from your client.

If your `$this->session->lang` is set by the user browser using `Accept-Language` http header, it can be tampered, See this [link](http://programmingpanda.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/xss-in-http-headers-accept-language.html) for a practical example.

Comment: Great thanks, but isn't there any way how to do it automatically in CodeIgniter?